# Wait for press enter in C inside a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, keypress, getchar

I'm writing a C program and I need to wait for the user to press any key to continue. When I use `getchar();` it waits for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to be pressed. But when I use it inside a `while` loop, it doesn't work. How can I make my code wait for any key to be pressed to continue the loop?

Here is my code sample. I am using GNU/Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int choice;
    while(1) {
        printf("1.Create Train\n");
        printf("2.Display Train\n");
        printf("3.Insert Bogie into Train\n");
        printf("4.Remove Bogie from Train\n");
        printf("5.Search Bogie into Train\n");
        printf("6.Reverse the Train\n");
        printf("7.Exit");
        printf("\nEnter Your choice : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Train Created.");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Train Displayed.");
                break;
            case 7:
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Invalid Input!!!\n");
        }

        printf("Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");
        getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `_getch` instead.

Comment: i'm using linux.not working.
 undefined reference to `_getchar'

Comment: I said `_getch`, not `_getchar`!!!

Comment: same error. undefined reference to `_getch`

Comment: It's in `conio.h` I think (and a simple web search would get you there too BTW).

Comment: I think you must use two `getchar()` instead of one. your previous `\n` read in `getchar()` so you need two of it.

Comment: @barakmanos I think there is no conio.h on linux. it's windows library.

Comment: @barakmanos i mention that. i'm using linux not windows. `conio.h` only available on windows.
@ParhamAlvani its work. but my question is `fflush(stdin)` why not work before `getchar()` ?

Comment: @TuxBot I think you must put your `fflush(stdin)` before your `getchar()` and after your `scanf()`

Comment: Just add another `getchar()` after your `scanf` or your `getchar()` and remove the `fflush`.

Comment: You can try to use `system("read -n1 -r ")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this code (with additional fflush)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int choice;
    while(1){
        printf("1.Create Train\n");
        // print other options
        printf("\nEnter Your choice : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        // do something with choice
        // ...
        // ask for ENTER key
        printf("Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");
        fflush(stdin); // option ONE to clean stdin
        getchar(); // wait for ENTER
    }
    return 0;
}
```

does not work properly.

Try this code (with loop):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int choice;
    while(1){
        printf("1.Create Train\n");
        // print other options
        printf("\nEnter Your choice : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        // do something with choice
        // ...
        // ask for ENTER key
        printf("Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");
        while(getchar()!='\n'); // option TWO to clean stdin
        getchar(); // wait for ENTER
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is Undefined Behavior and should never be used!

Comment: @CacahueteFrito agree (it was in the original code), so option 2 is preferable - `while(getchar()!='\n');`

Comment: But it still has a `fflush(stdin)` in the middle. Did you forget to remove it?

Comment: I would put two consecutive `while (getchar() != '\n');` in the end and remove the plain `getchar();`. Then you can remove that `fflush(stdin)` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer why fflush(stdin) will not work you can find here:

[How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` will read the input key pressed by you after entering your choice.
In this case <kbd>Enter</kbd> key ASCII 13 is read by `getchar()`

So you need to clear the input buffer or you can use other alternatives.

**Alternative 1:** use `getchar()` twice

```
{
    getchar(); // This will store the enter key
    getchar(); //This will get the character you press..hence wait for the key press

}
```

Comment: Double `getchar()` could not always work. E.g. if user enter string like "1abc" and press Enter (when asked for number).